# Problem with checkbox state after marking everyone as checked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

When I try to mark single checkboxes, it works. IF I then mark the topbox that changes everyone to marked, it also works. But when I try to undo the marks, everyone gets unmarked, except for the ones i clicked before clicking the "check everyone" box.

Ive tried editing state and fixing the input in the button. But it doesnt seem to work, no matter what.

```
state = {
        isAllSelected: false,
        checked: {}
    };

handleOnClick = (idx, checked) => {
            this.setState( {
                checked: {
                    ...this.state.checked,
                    [idx]: checked
                },
            })
    }


//For columns
<Checkbox id="headerCheckbox"
                 defaultChecked={false}
                 onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this,'all', !checked.all)}
                 checked={checked.all || false}
                 onChange={() => {}}
/>

//for rows
<Checkbox id={row._id} defaultChecked={false}
                onChange={() => {}}
                onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, index, !checked[index])}
                checked={checked[index] || checked.all || false}
  />
```

Expected result is that if I click on some of my boxes for rows, then the column one, it should mark everyone, which it does. When I then click again, its supposed to uncheck all the boxes in my table, but it only unchecks the ones I did not click before I clicked the "mark everyone" box

Comment: I recommend taking a look at https://react.tips/checkboxes-in-react-16/

Comment: @CWSites I just dont make it work doing it that way. Not with how I setup mine. My state is defined with checked: {}

Comment: @Jayavel yes, but my state is arrayless. Just an object of checkboxes

Comment: @Jayavel I edited my post now with state!

Comment: @stAMy do you need something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chck-all-uncheckall-checkbox ?

Comment: @stAMy  stackblitz.com/edit/react-chck-all-uncheckall-checkbox  is that worked ?

Comment: @Jayavel After some trying, your principals seems to be what I needed! Thank you so much and sorry for late reply! I just got it working yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your state like below, to get selected check box in state object :

from this :

```
 state = {
        isAllSelected: false,
        checked: {}
    };
```

to :
hope your data looks like this :

```
 const options = [
                {
                    name: "city",
                    value: "bangalore"
                },
                {
                    name: "city",
                    value: "chennai"
                },
                {
                    name: "city",
                    value: "delhi"
                }
            ];
```

and

```
this.state = {
        isAllSelected: false,
        checked: options.reduce((r, a) => {
          r[a.value] = false;
          return r;
        }, {}),
        checkList: options
    };
```

Now this.state.checked have obj like this : `{bangalore: false, chennai: false, delhi: false}`

Now in onChange event, change checked object value like below:

```
  onCheck(checkName, isChecked) { 
    let isAllChecked = (checkName === 'all' && isChecked);
    let isAllUnChecked = (checkName === 'all' && !isChecked);
    const checked = isChecked;

    const newChecked = {...this.state.checked};

    if(checkName === 'all' && isChecked) {
      Object.keys(newChecked).forEach(v => newChecked[v] = true)
    } else if(checkName === 'all' && !isChecked) {
      checkName === 'all' && Object.keys(newChecked).forEach(v => newChecked[v] = false);
    } else {
      newChecked = { ...newChecked, [checkName]: checked };
    }

    let isAllCheckedNew = Object.keys(newChecked).every(function(k){ return newChecked[k] === true });

   this.setState({
     checked: newChecked,
     isAllSelected: isAllCheckedNew || isAllChecked
   });
```

Full code demo available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chck-all-uncheckall-checkbox)